# Closing a figure in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am making a lot of plots and saving them to a file, it all works, but during the compilation I get the following message:

```
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
  fig = self.plt.figure(figsize=self.figsize)
```

So I think I could improve the code by closing the figures, I googled it and found that I should use `fig.close()`. However I get the following error `'Figure' object has no attribute 'close'`. How should I make it work?

This is the loop in which I create plots:

```
for i in years:
    ax = newdf.plot.barh(y=str(i), rot=0) 
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.savefig('C:\\Users\\rysza\\Desktop\\python data analysis\\zajecia3\\figure'+str(i)+'.jpeg',bbox_inches='tight')
    fig.close()
```

Comment: Please add library tag

Comment: It's `plt.close(fig)`, not `fig.close()`. Unless you provide a reputable source it's hard to read the question as anything other than a typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `fig.close()` with `plt.close(fig)`, [`close`](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html) is a function defined directly in the module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, matplotlib.pyplot.close(fig) , for more information refer this website
https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html